# Where can I find test vector of dragon and grain128?

Tags: stream-cipher

I don’t know how to find.
Like this picture shows.

[image]

Comment: If it's literally in the paper defining the cipher then I start to wonder if you're taking the Mickey.

Comment: I'm just using it for research

Comment: So I need the exact test vector, otherwise I don't know if I'm running the right code

Answer (score 1):

Google it. Dragon. See Appendix A below:

https://cr.yp.to/streamciphers/dragon-128/desc.pdf

Grain. See section 7 on the NIST webpage below:

[NIST Grain spec](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/lightweight-cryptography/documents/finalist-round/updated-spec-doc/grain-128aead-spec-final.pdf)

I trust you can now search for test vectors for other ciphers if necessary.

Comment: Thanks !!@kodlu

Comment: you can accept the answer if you are happy with it.